# How to format an author who only has a title (written by the "office") in a bibliography?

Tags: citation

(forgiveness if this is not the correct stackexchange - this one had the most and only relevant hits)

I am trying to record https://www.jcs.mil/Portals/36/Documents/Doctrine/pubs/jp1_0.pdf in my bibliography. The official author is "Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff".

Joint Chiefs of Staff is a group, and the Chairman is an individual in charge of the group. It is inappropriate to use General Mark Milley.

I am thinking just to use:

> Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff

but also variations on seem correct too

> Joint Chiefs of Staff, Chairman of the

Comment: Unless you're constrained by your chosen or designated style guide, I suggest you could just replicate the original attribution: ***STUART B. MUNSCH,** for Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at another document [CJCSI 3100.01C](https://dml.armywarcollege.edu/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/CJCSI-3100.01C-Joint-Strategic-Planning-System-2015.pdf), page 45. It seems that using the title of the office/duty is what is used.

a. Titles 6, 10, 22, and 50, United States Code (U.S.C.)

b. President of the United States, “The National Security Strategy of the United States”

c. President of the United States, “Unified Command Plan”

d. Secretary of Defense, “Guidance for Employment of the Force”

e. Secretary of Defense, “Defense Planning Guidance”

f. Secretary of Defense, “Global Force Management Implementation Guidance”

g. Secretary of Defense, March 2008, “Adaptive Planning Roadmap II”

h. Deputy Secretary of Defense memorandum, 14 February 2008, “Joint Capability Areas”

i. Chairman of the Joint Chiefs of Staff, “National Military Strategy of the United States”

Comment: If no better answer by Monday, will accept my own.

Comment: It depends on the style of your place of publication. For APA, I would do:

Reference: Chairman, Joint Chiefs of Staff. (2017). Countering air and missile threats (JP 3-01). https://www.jcs.mil/Portals/36/Documents/Doctrine/pubs/jp3_01_pa.pdf

In-Text (first citation): (Chairman, Joint Chiefs of Staff [CJCS], 2017)

In-Text (subsequent citations): (CJCS, 2017)

Answer (score 2):

You do not specify in which citation style, so I will give as many examples as I can:

APA

> Joint Chiefs of Staff. (2017). Countering air and missile threats (JP 3-01). https://www.jcs.mil/Portals/36/Documents/Doctrine/pubs/jp3_01_pa.pdf

CMOS

> Joint Chiefs of Staff, Doctrine for the Armed Forces of the United States, JP 1 (Washington, DC: Joint Chiefs of Staff, 2017), I-7, https://fas.org/irp/doddir/dod/jp1.pdf.

MLA

> Joint Chiefs of Staff. Department of Defense Dictionary of Military and Associated Terms. Washington, D.C. :Joint Chiefs of Staff : For sale by the Supt. of Docs., U.S. G.P.O., 1972.

You can find examples [at the University of Wisconsin's website](https://search.library.wisc.edu/catalog/999644826002121/cite) and [the Naval Postgraduate School](https://libguides.nps.edu/citation/apa)

Comment: Omitting the "Chairman" part?

Comment: It is properly abbreviated as CJCS.

Comment: Only the preface was written by Munsch for the CJCS. The document belongs to the organization.

Comment: Your links help me rethink how to search for the answer. Thanks!